# Is には a contraction of のには or ためには and how did it come to be like this ?

Tags: particles

,Hello, this is a question I've been wondering for ages but I can't find anything that answers clearly.

So firstly I have read in "a dictionary of japanese grammar" the のに/のには part on which it is written that when we add the particle は to のに, it is often contracted into には. 
It made complete sense to me but even then, I still find some cases where のには wouldn't be accepted whereas には is okay. For example I saw in the dictionary :

> 始発に乗るには四時に起きなくてはならない。

They explain that this には means 「場合には」 or 「時には」 so I believe this is the contraction of のには.
But in the following sentence :

> Huluを解約するには、どのようにするのですか？

I don't think のには would be okay. So I searched on the internet and found somewhere that someone was saying には is a contraction of ためには.

So who should I believe? 
Maybe には is something completely different that just happened to have almost the same meaning as ためには and のには？

Japanese people don't seem to know either, so I'm hoping to find someone who has a study paper or who has done a diachronic study to find the answer to this question

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in "a dictionary of japanese grammar" the のに/のには part on which it is written that when we add the particle は to のに, it is often contracted into には.
>
> > 始発に乗るには四時に起きなくてはならない。
>
> They explain that this には means 「場合には」 or 「時には」 so I believe this is the contraction of のには.

Correct. ためには is my preference; 始発に乗るためには (**"ため" is another noun**).
Also nothing wrong to say 始発に乗るのには.

> But in the following sentence :
>
> > Huluを解約するには、どのようにするのですか？

In this case also, 解約するのには is actually the fully spelled version. Of course, you can switch this nominalizing particle, の, to another noun; 解約するためには.

I feel, to use 場合 or 時, it's more natural to say 解約**したい場合**（に）は or 解約**したいとき**（に）は.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you would say that には is a contraction of のには　but not of ためには even though it has similar meaning in some cases ? I am actually trying to understand where exactly には comes from so it will help me to understand fully how to distinguish のには and ためには. If you have more informations on this I would greatly appreciate

Comment: Well, I don't mind at all. I think of には as the contraction of either のには or ためには. I can't predict whether ためには always successfully replaces のには though.

Comment: の is the one that is more versatile as the nominalizer, the nominalizing particle. This can be replaced by もの, こと, とき, ため etc. depending on the context.